# Do GPU's have caching systems or an operating system like a CPU does?

Tags: gpu, gpgpu

In terms of an operating system, does a GPU have some type of software on it to manage virtual memory, or context switching?

And in terms of hardware, does it have some type of caching system, or a TLB?

Comment: Please specify what you're trying to do and what GPU hardware you're using, by clicking on [edit] and adding the extremely useful information to your original question, so all can see it. Comments like this are intended to help you shape and refine your question post to zero in on what you want so we can provide the most useful answer.

Comment: CPUs don’t have an operation system.

Comment: Did you mean GPUs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different GPUs handle this differently, [as documented here](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/unified-memory-cuda-beginners/). The [Pascal series of GPUs](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/data-center/pascal-gpu-architecture/) share memory with the OS so there's no separate virtual memory.

Comment: Pascal most definitely has dedicated video memory (VRAM). However, DX12, CUDA, Vulcan handle controlling the GPU.

Comment: Dedicated VRAM? Yes. Virtual? Not as Windows or *ix knows virtual (i.e., swapfiles).